# ServiceStack Message queue .outq max size is 100?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-bsd, servicestack.redis

I'm setting up a message queue using ServiceStack-v3 that looks like this

> ClaimImport -> Validation -> Success

I've added hundreds of `ClaimImports` with no problem, the `.inq` count is correct. The issue is I want to see how many claims were imported by checking the `ClaimsImport.outq`. It never seems to go past 101. Is there some other way I could check this, or is this max limit intentional?

[image: Max 101 items in dlq]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default limit added on [RedisMessageQueueClient.MaxSuccessQueueSize](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.Redis/Messaging/RedisMessageQueueClient.cs#L35). The purpose of the `.outq` is to be a rolling log of recently processed messages.

Clients can subscribe to the `QueueNames.TopicOut` to get notified when a message is published to the `.outq`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I was hoping to get metrics out of it, but with this knowledge I realized its not meant to do this.